# Converter o valor do resultado da consulta sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho a consulta que me retornar dois resultados onde gostaria de formatar ele para vim no formato adequado. Como poderia fazer isso?

```html
select *, sum(valor) as ValorSoma, count(pedido) as QtdPedido from tb_vendas
where idvendas > 0
and data_venda between '05/10/2015' and '11/04/2016'
and vendedor = ''
group by cliente 
order by QtdPedido desc
```

ValorSoma tipo decimal

QtdPedido tipo inteiro

Agradeço

Comment: Deixa eu ver se eu entendi , você esta usando está consulta em algum lugar do seu sistema ? e quer armazenar um duas variáveis uma do tipo decimal outra do tipo inteiro ? ou não tem nada a ver ?

Comment: O resultado de ValorSoma é QtdPedido  vem como uma string

Comment: Você quer qual formato?

Answer (score 0):

Se você deseja que o resultado seja do tipo numérico, é necessário fazer um `CAST` ou `CONVERT`. Com você não especificou qual SGBD, tomei a liberdade de exemplificar em SQL Server:

```
select 
  *, 
  CAST(sum(valor) AS NUMERIC(10,2)) as ValorSoma, 
  CAST(count(pedido) AS INTEGER) as QtdPedido 
from tb_vendas
where 
  idvendas > 0
  and data_venda between '05/10/2015' and '11/04/2016'
  and vendedor = ''
group by cliente 
order by QtdPedido desc
```

O exemplo acima retorna o campo ValorSoma com tipo `Numeric` e QtdPedido com o tipo `Integer`.